# How to write switch case in python with dictionary

Tags: python

I am using nested if in my python code, my example code is :

```
message = event_data["event"]
    if message.get("subtype") is None :

       if "friday" in message.get('text'):
          callfridayfunction()

       if "saturday" in message.get('text'):
          callsaturdayfunction()

       if "monday" in message.get('text'):
          callmondayfunction()
```

How can I write this as a switch case or using dictionary ? Please help

Comment: What does `message['text']` look like for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

This may be the closest to what you want. This will work if multiple days are in the text also.

```
days_switch = {
    'monday': callmondayfunction,
    'saturday': callsaturdayfunction
    'friday': callfridayfunction
}

message = event_data["event"]
if message.get("subtype") is None :
    text = message.get('text', '')
    days = set(text.split()) & set(days_switch)
    for day in days:
        days_switch[day]()
```

if you know there aren't multiple days in the text, then the loop isn't needed.

```
days_switch[set(text.split()) & set(days_switch)]()
```